# How can I post a custom equation in a cell based on another cell's value?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, excel-formula, formula

I can't seem to figure out why my code won't work.

I am trying to insert a formula that multiplies a cost by an inflation factor depending on the rating that is inputted. The For loop goes through 7 rows of data in the same column (5), fetches the rating, and assigns a custom formula based on this rating. When I go through the code step by step, the values are all correct and I am able to output the correct equation in a message box. Not sure why I can't post it to the cell though... I think it has something to do with the fact that I'm using `Range(Cells(j, 4))` instead of something like `Range("D15")`

It's important to note that I named some cells `Inflation1` through `Inflation5`.

Ex: If in cell `E4` the rating is 2, the code should paste the formula `=Inflation2*D4` in cell `D15`.

Here's the code:

```
Sub InflationFactor()
Dim CurrentRow As Long
CurrentRow = 4
Dim Rating As Long
Dim j As Long
j = 15

For i = CurrentRow To CurrentRow + 6
    Rating = Cells(i, 5).Value
    Sheet1.Range(Cells(j, 4)).Formula = "=Inflation" + Str(Rating) + "*D" + Str(i)
    i = i + 1
    j = j + 1
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify: do you have a variable named "Sheet1"? If you don't you'll want to reference it like Sheets("Sheet1"). Also, are you doing all of this on the same sheet, or do you want to output onto a different sheet based on the values in this sheet?

Comment: Even if you get the formula to paste, it will throw an error as I do not know of a formula `Inflation`.  But the string should be `"=Inflation" & Rating & "*D" & i`

Comment: @Mikegrann There's no variable named Sheet1. I tried using Sheets("Sheet1") and it seems to work but it's saying "Run-time error '9'. Subscript out of range."

Comment: UPDATE: Everything works after I changed the "+" to "&" in my formula. Thanks to @Mikegrann and Scott for the help.